# check the 'checked' value of all children checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, my JS is not the best, I need some help on something I am sure is simple.

Basically I have my parent node (it can change, but that's okay, I'm getting the Parent correctly), but I now need to know if every child checkbox of that parent is checked (if so return 1) or if 1 or more child checkboxes is unchecked return 0.

Any help would be great!

Comment: sorry guys, im a new member, wasn't aware of that, fixed now! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `:not` combined with `:checked` is what you want

```
var numUnchecked = 
    $(parentNode).find("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").length;

if (numUnchecked > 0)
   alert("Some not checked");
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Na7dj/1/)

So for your specific question, it would be something like this

```
function areAllChecked() {
    var parentNode = $("#parent");
    var numUnchecked = 
        parentNode.find("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").length;
    return numUnchecked > 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: great, it works, I missed the :not, 3 hours wasted, pretty much everything else I had! Thanks again champ